# Why do I get rows of zeros in my 2D fft?

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to replicate the results from a paper.

"Two-dimensional Fourier Transform (2D-FT) in space and time along sections of constant latitude (east-west) and longitude (north-south) were used to characterize the spectrum of the simulated flux variability south of 40degS." - Lenton et al(2006)
The figures published show "the log of the variance of the 2D-FT".

I have tried to create an array consisting of the seasonal cycle of similar data as well as the noise. I have defined the noise as the original array minus the signal array.

Here is the code that I used to plot the 2D-FT of the signal array averaged in latitude:

```
import numpy as np

from numpy import ma
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from Scientific.IO.NetCDF import NetCDFFile 

### input directory 
indir = '/home/nicholas/data/'

### get the flux data which is in
### [time(5day ave for 10 years),latitude,longitude]
nc = NetCDFFile(indir + 'CFLX_2000_2009.nc','r')
cflux_southern_ocean  = nc.variables['Cflx'][:,10:50,:]
cflux_southern_ocean  = ma.masked_values(cflux_southern_ocean,1e+20) # mask land
nc.close()

cflux = cflux_southern_ocean*1e08 # change units of data from mmol/m^2/s

### create an array that consists of the seasonal signal fro each pixel
year_stack = np.split(cflux, 10, axis=0)
year_stack = np.array(year_stack)
signal_array = np.tile(np.mean(year_stack, axis=0), (10, 1, 1))
signal_array = ma.masked_where(signal_array > 1e20, signal_array) # need to mask
### average the array over latitude(or longitude)
signal_time_lon = ma.mean(signal_array, axis=1)

### do a 2D Fourier Transform of the time/space image
ft = np.fft.fft2(signal_time_lon)
mgft = np.abs(ft)   
ps = mgft**2 
log_ps = np.log(mgft)
log_mgft= np.log(mgft)
```

Every second row of the ft consists completely of zeros. Why is this?
Would it be acceptable to add a randomly small number to the signal to avoid this.

```
signal_time_lon = signal_time_lon + np.random.randint(0,9,size=(730, 182))*1e-05
```

EDIT: Adding images and clarify meaning

The output of rfft2 still appears to be a complex array. Using fftshift shifts the edges of the image to the centre; I still have a power spectrum regardless. I expect that the reason that I get rows of  zeros is that I have re-created the timeseries for each pixel. The ft[0, 0] pixel contains the mean of the signal. So the ft[1, 0] corresponds to a sinusoid with one cycle over the entire signal in the rows of the starting image.

Here are is the starting image using following code:
[image: Starting image]

```
plt.pcolormesh(signal_time_lon); plt.colorbar(); plt.axis('tight')
```

Here is result using following code:
[image]

```
ft = np.fft.rfft2(signal_time_lon)
mgft = np.abs(ft)   
ps = mgft**2                    
log_ps = np.log1p(mgft)
plt.pcolormesh(log_ps); plt.colorbar(); plt.axis('tight')
```

It may not be clear in the image but it is only every second row that contains completely zeros. Every tenth pixel (log_ps[10, 0]) is a high value. The other pixels (log_ps[2, 0], log_ps[4, 0] etc) have very low values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
In [59]: from scipy import absolute, fft

In [60]: absolute(fft([1,2,3,4]))
Out[60]: array([ 10.        ,   2.82842712,   2.        ,   2.82842712])

In [61]: absolute(fft([1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4]))
Out[61]: 
array([ 20.        ,   0.        ,   5.65685425,   0.        ,
         4.        ,   0.        ,   5.65685425,   0.        ])

In [62]: absolute(fft([1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4]))
Out[62]: 
array([ 30.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,   8.48528137,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   6.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   8.48528137,   0.        ,   0.        ])
```

If `X[k] = fft(x)`, and `Y[k] = fft([x x])`, then `Y[2k] = 2*X[k]` for `k in {0, 1, ..., N-1}` and zero otherwise.

Therefore, I would look into how your `signal_time_lon` is being tiled. That may be where the problem lies.

Comment: Thanks. So the problem lies in that I have deliberately constructed a time-series which repeats itself ten times. Therefore log_ps[10, :], corresponding to the sinusoid with ten cycles over the time-series will be very bright/high and all other pixels will be close to zero or zero. Y[10k] = 10*K[k] for k in {0, 1, ..., N-1}

Comment: In your example there was no high frequency variability. But in my data there should be high frequency variability and that is not really showing. Or is the high frequency variability just very small in comparison to the low frequency variability (ten cycle tiled timeseries).

Comment: Yes, the energy in the high-frequency components is probably just small as is often the case with many real-world signals. Try to plot the values on a log scale (not a log(1+x) scale). Or change the vmin/vmax parameters of your plot.